# Swift: How to Reuse Custom View Loaded from Nib

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard, nib

I have a custom cell in my app and I want to reuse it in other places. However, it would not be in a `UITableView` but rather in the `UIScrollView`'s content view. Considering it is possible to use it this way, the challenge I am facing is how to load from Nib once and reuse this cell many times. I tried:

```
var myReusableCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! SearchViewCell
```

When I loop through data array to create instances of `myReusableCell` this would obviously slow down my app. I am looking for ways to reuse this Nib within a loop.

```
for (index, dataObject) in self.dataObjects {
   var myReusableCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! SearchViewCell //slow!
}
```

I attempted to load it outside `for` loop and make a copy of the cell to reuse it with :

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self))
```

but unsuccessful. Please advise if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

first at all I need to say it sounds like is an UITableView or UICollectionView use case.
Having said that, I don't sure but you could trying a deep copy

```
var myReusableCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SearchViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! SearchViewCell
    for (index, dataObject) in self.dataObjects {
        if let cell = myReusableCell.copy() as? SearchViewCell {
            // TODO update your dataObject values
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you. Using copy() crashes my app with error `SearchViewCell copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Comment: Hi @Vad you can provide an implementation of copyWithZone function and too conform to NSCopying protocol in your SearchViewcell to explain it how to copy your data.
more info here https://robnapier.net/implementing-nscopying